# DirectX and OpenCL interop on Intel UHD - hangs on releasing DX textures

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl, intel, directx-11

I am trying to use DirectX textures inside OpenCL compute workflow. The code works fine on nVidia (using OpenCL), but on Intel UHD (11th gen) the call to release resources just waits indefinitely as if some event did not complete.

I use `cl::` wrappers such as `cl::CommandQueue`.

In gist:

```cpp
// clGpuCtx is created and passed into a function
// it mostly stores the queue and conntext for processing

cl::CommandQueue& clQueue = clGpuCtx->getClCommandQueue(); // acquire the queue
cl::Context& clCtx = clGpuCtx->getClContext(); // acquire the context

// api basically stores valid function pointers to dx interop methods depending on
// whether KHR or NV extensions are available for the queue/platform
// it uses the following code to retrieve the address for a given function for KHR:
// 
// enqueueReleaseD3D11Objects = reinterpret_cast<clEnqueueReleaseD3D11ObjectsKHR_fn>(
//        clGetExtensionFunctionAddressForPlatform( clPlatform(), "clEnqueueReleaseD3D11ObjectsKHR" ) );
// 
// NV code is analogous

auto api = getClDxInteropAPI( clQueue );

cl_int clErr;

// dxTexture is passed into a function and is a valid ID3D11Texture2D
auto clImg = api->createFromD3D11Texture2D( clCtx(), CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, dxTexture, 0, &clErr );
if ( clErr != CL_SUCCESS ) {
        return;
}

clErrCheck( api->enqueueAcquireD3D11Objects( clQueue(), 1, &clImg, 0, NULL, NULL ),
                "unable to acquire OCL DirectX resource" );

resources.emplace_back(clImg);

// ... rendering code
   
clErrCheck( clQueue.finish(), "Error finishing OpenCL queue" );
 
cl_uint numResources = resources.size();
// the command below causes the execution to continue indefinately 
clErrCheck( api->enqueueReleaseD3D11Objects( clQueue(), numResources, resources.data(), 0, nullptr, nullptr ),
                "unable to release OCL DirectX resource" );
```

- The same code works fine with nVidia and AMD GPUs
- The same code works with native OpenCL images and buffers
- I tried releasing resources one by one and all at once, the result is the same
- I tried releasing resources before and after queue.finish
- I made sure that the command queue and contexts for acquiring and releasing match

What am I missing?